# Session_End in Global.asax.cs not firing using forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, session-timeout

I have an asp.net 4.0 application that is using forms authentication set to a timeout at 45 minutes. I would like to redirect the user to a timeout page when the session has expired. Can anyone tell me how to do this? I am running .net 4.0.

web.config has:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"
    defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="45"
    requireSSL="false">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Global.asax.cs file has:

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Timeout.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to do a redirect in the `Session_End` method. It's not running as a result of a request, so it doesn't have a `Response` object and there is no response to redirect anywhere.

It's not possible to do anything in the browser as a result of the session expiring. The HTTP protocol is request oriented, so there is no way to push a message from the server to the browser without the browser asking for it.

The browser just can't find out if the session has expired or not. If you would poll the server to check if the session has expired, it would keep the session alive, defeating the purpose of the timeout.

You can make a redirect after 45 minutes using just client script:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = '/Timeout.aspx';
}, 1000*45*60);
```

However, this will make the redirect only based on the time since this browser window last contacted the server. If you have more than one browser window for the same session, it's possible that the session has actually not timed out.

Comment: the redirect could be a refresh even, or some kind of ajax call that checks session data.

Comment: You're right. You think i could use something like jQuery idleTimer (http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/), set it to 45 minutes like you did with (window.setTimeout) and redirect? You think that might work well? I can wait for 45 minutes idle time and force a logout/session-end/redirect.

Comment: @krefftc: I didn't read much on the page that you linked to, due to it's very jerky and annoying animations, but I think that the idle timer tries to find out if the user is active in the browser or not. The session timeout doesn't care at all what the user does in the browser unless the browser fetches something from the server, so it's not at all affected by that. Thus, the `setTimeout` would better correspond to when the session times out on the server.

Comment: the site i posted had beautiful animations of Christmas snowflakes blowing in your face, what's not to love?...no but seriously, i get what you're saying, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How is your session state implemented? Session_End only works when you are using InProc.

See http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20021016.asp

Comment: I guess whatever session state forms authentication uses.

Comment: Forms Authentication != Session State.

Comment: Well at any rate the default is InProc. You'd have to manually change it to SQL Server or whatever else. Yes I know this is 7 years later, but I don't care.

Answer (score 0):

On MVC you can adding this code in _ViewStart.cshtml

_ViewStart.cshtml:

```
@{
     Response.AddHeader("Refresh",Convert.ToString((Session.Timeout * 60) + 5));      

     if(Session.IsNewSession)  
         Response.Redirect(“Logout.aspx");// or another page which you want.
}
```

[How to Redirect on Session End](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27748260/2736742)