# Session_End does not fire?

Tags: asp.net, session

I want to sign out a user when his session times out. So used following code in Global.asax:

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
```

But seems `session_end` never fires. Any idea how can fix it? I'm using ASP.NET with default settings.

Comment: Did you really wait 20 minutes for that to event to fire?

Comment: @leppie: definitely yes! I also replaced that line with this: "throw new Exception("");" but still does not work.

Comment: @InSane: How can ensure this? I know my session really expires after a specific time. So it seems that it is InProc

Comment: To ensure your session state mode, goto your web.config file and find a tag called SessionState. There will be an attribute named mode="" If the value of your attribute is In-Proc, only then this event will fire. For anything else event will not fire.

Comment: @Subhasg Dike, @InSane: I have not such a thing in web.config. What's the default value?

Comment: @afsharm - It would be defaulted based on your machine.config value. Should be "Inproc" most likely. Thats usually the default

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You may set some Session data in Session_Start. Without this, Session_End will not be fired.
see [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1384474.aspx/1)

> Also another very important thing to note here is that if you do not save anything in the session the Session_End event will not fire. There must be something saved in the session atleast once for the Session_End event to fire. This also means that if you save something in the session in the first request and abandon the session in the same request the Sesison_End event will not fire, as there was nothing saved in the session ever.

Comment: Very interesting; something I did not know. Also makes a lot of sense. IMHO, this is the answer.

Comment: I have the same Problem but I do save something (Session["abc"] = "xyz";) in Session_Start. But it does not work. :(

Comment: The Session_OnEnd event is not supported if the session Mode property is set to a value other than InProc, which is the default mode. Is it your case?

Comment: I'll add that simply doing `var sessionID = Session.SessionID` inside of Session_Start was enough to get Session_End to fire for me.

Answer (score 10):

In your web.config you need to have the sessionState element as a child of the  element

```
<configuration>
     <system.web>
          <sessionState mode="InProc" />
          .....
     </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Also worth nothing is that Session_End does NOT work with any sessionState other than InProc.

Comment: I changed the session to InProc. But session_end does not fire yet.

Comment: Are you running this in IIS or in Visual Studio, if it's in VisualStudio with the WebDev then you wont see the event fire. To test it you will need to put your website in IIS and attach the debugger to w3wp.exe

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if it is a feature or bug. Or may be I don't understand enough session managment in ASP.NET. But this is what I found.

Session_End does not fire in ASP.NET MVC 4 (with default settings for sessionState element in web.config) if Session_Start is not declared.

So you need declare Session_Start to catch Session_End :)

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) { }

protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Debug.WriteLine("End. " + Session.SessionID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it never fires ?

As I understand it `Session_End` has nothing to do with the current request because ASP.NET session is terminated by the timeout AFTER the last request from the client has arrived. The call to `FormsAuthenticaion.SignOut` manipulates authentication cookies and therefore has no effect without any connectivity from the client (browser).

Take a look at this question (which has an answer) - the problem is more or less similar to yours so you might find a right solution:

[Session_End in Global.asax.cs not firing using forms authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453365/session-end-in-global-asax-cs-not-firing-using-forms-authentication)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how its working, but it will fire when i close my browser after time out period.

```
  public void Session_End(Object sender, SessionEndedEventArgs e)
  {
  }
```

Call this from

```
  Application_Start() Event

  SessionEndModule.SessionEnd += new SessionEndEventHandler(Session_End);
```