# Send an email when session expires

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In have a web app where session has the idletimeoout, 2 hours. Now when the session is idle for 2 hours I need to send an email. How to I raise an event on session expire?

```
services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                // Session timeout is at 2 hours
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
            }); /
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Global.asax.cs file you can add the event handler:

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Send your email
}
```

Note that you may need to [add something to the session to ensure that the end event is raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813462/session-end-does-not-fire). You can ensure that this happens by adding a dummy variable when the session is created:

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
    Session["SessionID"] = Session.SessionID;
}
```