# Need user to login again once user Session gets End

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-management

Hi My problem is I need to redirect to the login page again when the user session gets end. and I want user to login again but when I refresh the page after session timeout gets completed it opens automatically logged in user without asking for login again. That's what I need to avoid I want user to login again once the user session gets over.

Answer (score 1):

Use Session_End Event and redirect the user to Login Page, but Session_End event fires only when you set any value in Session_Start Event.

As the sample code in not there in your question, My suggestion is try setting one dummy value in Session_Start and test the application. Upon working you can modify accordingly

Reference Links :

> [Session_End does not fire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813462/session-end-does-not-fire)
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx