# Session_End Event not fire

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i want to have number of people is online.
i wrote this code in Session_End :

```
    protected void ()
    {
        int online = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Application["Online"].ToString());
        online -= 1;
        HttpContext.Current.Application["Online"] = online;
    }
```

Session_End Event not firing and `online` value is same.
The `Session_Start` works well and gave correct value, so i think problem is in Session_End Event.

Session_Start Code Is :

```
    protected void Session_Start()
    {
        int online = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Application["Online"].ToString());
        online += 1;
        HttpContext.Current.Application["Online"] = online;
        //After This Codes ,i add Visit Log Using user ip into database(may help)
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session\_End does not fire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813462/session-end-does-not-fire)

Comment: If you need to maintain state beyond a single session and Application, you need some form of state persistence, typically a database, that you write/read through too. You can try something like this `var loggedInUsers = (Dictionary<string datetime="">)HttpRuntime.Cache["LoggedInUsers"]`